# c++ enum convertibility to int?

Tags: c++, enums

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/ :

> Values of enumerated types declared with enum are implicitly convertible to the integer type int, and vice versa. In fact, the elements of such an enum are always assigned an integer numerical equivalent internally, of which they become an alias. If it is not specified otherwise, the integer value equivalent to the first possible value is 0, the equivalent to the second is 1, to the third is 2, and so on...

So, following this idea, I wanted to see if the following sample would work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum colors {white, yellow, red, green, blue, black};

int main()
{
  colors a{3};
  colors b{1};
  colors c{a-b};
  cout << c << '\n' << (c == red) << '\n' << c+20 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

And it works as expected, but only if I set the `-fpermissive` flag, otherwise `g++` spits out compilation errors. And even with this flag set I am still presented with a number of warnings, like this: `invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘colors’`

If I understand the documentation correctly the above sample should be 100% compliant with the standard. However, apparently according to `g++` it is not (note the word "*invalid*").

I even had the idea to push this convertibility even further and try something like this: `colors d{yellow}; d++;` (hoping for `d` becoming `red`). However, this time I cannot make this working. I get:

```
enum.cpp:13:22: warning: no ‘operator++(int)’ declared for postfix ‘++’, trying prefix operator instead [-fpermissive]
   colors d{yellow}; d++;
                      ^
enum.cpp:13:22: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘colors’)
```

Is the code in my sample correct? If so, is it possible to increment an `enum` variable as described above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, your code is not correct and the error message tells one of the reasons.

Comment: You should probably make the `int` compatibility explicit: [`enum : int colors { /* ... */ }`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Could you very kindly elaborate it a little bit more?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `enum : int colors {white, yellow, red, green, blue, black};` gives out an array of errors on its own... :(

Comment: Sorry a typo. Should have been `enum colors  : int {white, yellow, red, green, blue, black};` as stated in the linked reference.

Comment: Warning is a way for compiler to accept valid code but warns users about *dangerous* pattern.